# exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run my server in my windows 11.
When I am using `docker compose up mssql_server`, it always shows me `exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory`, but in my docker file, `entrypoint.sh` does exist.

My Dockerfile:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    
    # Change to root to perform mkdir
    USER root
    # Create a config directory
    RUN mkdir -p /usr/config
    
    # set mssql as owner of the app directory
    RUN chown mssql /usr/config
    
    WORKDIR /usr/config
    
    # Bundle config source
    COPY src/db/ /usr/config/
    
    RUN echo ls /usr/config
    # Grant permissions for to our scripts to be executable
    RUN chmod +x /usr/config/entrypoint.sh
    RUN chmod +x /usr/config/configure-db.sh
    
    # change back to user mssql
    USER mssql
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

My compose file:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      mssql_server:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: src/db/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "1433:1433"
        environment:
          ACCEPT_EULA: Y
          MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: Password@126
          SQL_DEFAULT_USER: db_app_dev
          SQL_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: Password@126
          SQL_DEFAULT_DB: TestDB
        healthcheck:
          test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -Q "SELECT 1"
          start_period: 5s
          start_interval: 5s
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 5
        volumes:
          - mssql_data:/var/opt/mssql
    
      sep_server:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: src/server/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
          mssql_server:
            condition: service_healthy
            required: true
        environment:
          DB_USR: db_app_dev
          DB_PASSWD: Password@126
          DB_ADDR: mssql_server
          DB_PORT: 1433
          DB_NAME: TestDB
        tty: true
    
    volumes:
      mssql_data:
```

Under my docker desktop:
[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried using `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/config/entrypoint.sh"]` ?

Comment: Yes i did use before, but failed. I guess the problem is because it is unable to create the volume. When i run "docker compose up mssql_server", it only created Network and my container

Comment: When you specify entrypoint value longpath, I think you are getting another error. Could you please share the error message you're receiving?

Comment: Does the `entrypoint.sh` script have DOS line endings?  I could see that causing problems like this.  What is the very first line of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the last line in your dockerfile to this lines:
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 0700 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]